# format getting rounded off by a large amount using Intl.NumberFormat

Tags: javascript, format, decimal, currency

```
let just_the_number = '8973565';

const just_the_number_formatted = Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", { minimumFractionDigits: 0 }).format(parseFloat(just_the_number));
console.log(just_the_number_formatted)

let formatted_amount = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "INR",
      notation: "compact",
      compactDisplay: "long",
    }).format(just_the_number);

console.log(formatted_amount) // prints ₹90L
```

formatted_amount is getting rounded off by a large amount here.
I want the above printed ₹89.73L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` options to customize behaviour for decimal places.

Note that it will still get rounded.

For example:

```
let just_the_number = '8973565';

let formatted_amount = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "INR",
      notation: "compact",
      compactDisplay: "long",
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    }).format(just_the_number);

console.log(formatted_amount) // prints ₹89.74L
```